# How to stop subprocess.Popen() write desc in terminal

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am using `subprocess.Popen()` then redirecting log output to a file but in terminal it shows the description something like this:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time   Time   Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total  Spent  Left  Speed
100  772k    0  772k    0     0  2576k    0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5363k
```

How can i stop it displaying in terminal so that i can give some meaning statements to the end user.

The code snippet is

```
fo = open(dump_file_path, 'wb')

stdout = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = fo,)
```

Comment: What is `cmd`?  Presumably it is writing to stderr, maybe you want to redirect that to the log file too?

Comment: cmd is the command i have used to execute which returns some text and i want to write to a file,  cmd = ls -l | grep "tpd" ...No i didnt want the stderr to redirect to log file so i will make the stderr to false..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the output even if subprocess' stdout is redirected to a file then either the child process writes to stderr or directly to terminal.

To check redirect `stderr` temporarily to `STDOUT` and see whether the output is still visible.

If you don't want to redirect stderr of the whole pipeline; you could try to redirect only those commands that produce undesired output on stderr e.g., `curl` has `--stderr` option. Or other options that control the progress report.

To redirect the output that is written directly to terminal; you could use `pty` (pseudoterminal):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pty
import sys

with open(dump_file_path, 'wb') as file:
    def read(fd):
        data = os.read(fd, 1024)
        file.write(data)
        file.flush()
        return data

    pty.spawn(['/bin/sh', '-c', cmd], read)
```